# Google speech to text API for languages other than English

Tags: android, api, speech-recognition, speech

Is there an API for speech to text for languages other then English? I know the API for English (http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html) but I want be able to recognize speech in my language as e.g. Google Maps or Search do. It can even be general API, not Android API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html says:

*Google's servers currently support English, Mandarin Chinese, and Japanese. The web search model is available in all three languages, while free-form has primarily been optimized for English. As we work hard to support more models in more languages, and to improve the accuracy of the speech recognition technology we use in our products, Android developers who integrate speech capabilities directly into their applications can reap the benefits as well.*

When you use the intent, set the value for EXTRA_LANGUAGE. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_LANGUAGE

Comment: Link rot has happened here...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's Web Speech API, you record the sound on your local machine and it is send to an external server, you can control some variants like when to stop or start the recognition and some other things. There is even a variable that you can set for different languages.

var langs = [['en-US', 'United States'],['es-AR', 'Argentina']];

For more information here's a link:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API